# Everything shimmered "through" the heat haze OR Everything shimmered "in" the heat haze

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct?

> Everything shimmered **through** the heat haze
>   OR
>   Everything shimmered **in** the heat haze

Comment: Always mention the complete question in the body, not in the title.

Comment: *Through* seems to imply 'in spite of', whereas *in* could suggest 'because of', though not strictly necessarily. Does the 'heat haze' contribute to or restrict the 'shimmering'? By the way 'heat haze' is itself a shimmering phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything shimmered **in** the heat haze

*Heat haze* is itself a phenomenon of shimmering in the air.

Use of the preposition *through* suggests a contrast:
*It is visible through this haze*: The haze is obstructing, yet it can be seen. In spite of the haze, it is visible.

The use of *in* suggests causative or helpful contribution:
*It is visible in day light*: Because of day light; helped by day light.

It may be subjective, though.

Comment: This answer is correct. While you *could* say something "shimmered through" but it would refer to a shimmering object you saw through the haze. It is more applicable for something shimmering on the bottom of a body of water. In the context of heat, "in" is almost certainly correct.